# Making Excel file with PHPExcel, each column writing twice

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, phpexcel

SOLVED HERE:
I just needed to change this line

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

to

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
```

I am using PHPExcel to pull data from mySQL database to create the XLS file. I'm writing two columns: TITLE and VIEWS. (title is an actual column in the db table, views is a count of how many times each title appears in the table).

The data writes to the XLS file, the problem is that each column is writing twice:

|-------A-------|-------B-------|-------C-------|-------D-------|

5 ---TITLE---|---VIEWS---|

6 ---Title 1---|----Title 1----|-------3--------|-------3-------|

7 ---Title 2---|----Title 2----|-------6--------|-------6-------|

8 ---Title 3---|----Title 3----|-------4--------|-------4-------|

How do I fix this so that it displays each column once?

my code:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
      titles.title,
      COUNT(DISTINCT history.id) AS `count`
    FROM
      user_history titles
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      user_history history
    ON
      titles.title = history.title
    ";


    $sql .= "
    GROUP BY 
      titles.title
    ORDER BY 
      titles.title
    ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
$headings = array('Title', 'Views');

if ($result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())) {


    $rowNumber = 5;
    $col = 'A';
    foreach($headings as $heading) {
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading);
       $col++;
    }

    // Loop through the result set
    $rowNumber = 6;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $col = 'A';
       foreach($row as $cell) {
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
          $col++;
       }
       $rowNumber++;
    }
```

Comment: If you don't need any special formatting, have you considered just writing a CSV file?

Comment: @SimpleCoder - I do need special formatting.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do this for a pdo seems like always does a row fetch anyways? http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: I did PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because your join is lossless.

You are getting redundant information **twice**

Just do this for your query:

```
SELECT
  titles.title,
  COUNT(DISTINCT titles.id) AS `count`
FROM user_history titles
GROUP BY titles.title
ORDER BY titles.title;
```